# Orthonormal basis complex vector space $(1,i,0)$ and $(1,1,1)$

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-analysis

> Find an orthonormal basis for the subspaces $\mathbb{C}^3$ generated by the following vectors:
>   $(1,i,0)$ and $(1,1,1)$ in which $i$ is the imaginary root.

I took the first vector and tried to normalized it in the following way:
$\langle u,v\rangle=u\times\bar{v}$ in which $\bar{v}$ is the conjugate.

$\frac{(1,i,0)}{||(1,i,0)||}=\frac{(1,i,0)}{\langle(1,i,0)\rangle^{\frac{1}{2}}}=\frac{(1,i,0)}{\sqrt{2}}=(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},\frac{i}{\sqrt{2}},0)$

However the vector is not a unit vector because $||(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},\frac{i}{\sqrt{2}},0)||=0$.

There is another problem $\dim\mathbb{C}^3=3$ and it is only provided two vectors for the basis.

**Questions:**

**1)** What is failing on the normalization of the first vector?
After comments:

Normalization is right since $||(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},\frac{i}{\sqrt{2}},0)||=\langle,(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},\frac{i}{\sqrt{2}},0,(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},\frac{i}{\sqrt{2}},0)\rangle^\frac{1}{2}=1$. because of the conjugate.

**2)** Am I supposed to get another vector to orthogonalnalize?

**3)** Could someone solve  the question? I am self-studying and the book has no solutions.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: $$||(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},\frac{i}{\sqrt{2}},0)||=0$$ is wrong since $||v||=0$ if and only if $v$ is the zero vector

Comment: @ I forgot the conjugate you are right!

Comment: $\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\times\left(\overline{\frac{1}{2}}\right)+\left(\frac{i}{2}\right)\times\left(\overline{\frac{i}{2}}\right)+0\times\overline{0}$.

Comment: If you are interested in a general method: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process

Comment: Look again at the problem statement: “Find an orthonormal basis for the **subspaces**...” You don’t get a third vector to work with because you’re only looking at the subspace generated by the two given vectors.

Comment: Right! Attention deficit!

Answer (score 1):

The norm of something complex is $z z^* = z^2$, meaning the complex conjugate of $z$. I think you are on the right track.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! I hope you stay around and contribute to the site.

Comment: I am only a simple physicist trying to find my path in this mathy world. 

Exterior algebra rocks.